# duplicate key value error that is difficult to understand

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
               user_id                |              project_id              | permission
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------
 5911e84b-ab6f-4a51-942e-dab979882725 | b4f6d926-ac69-461f-9fd7-1992a1b1c5bc | owner
 7e3581a4-f542-4abc-bbda-36fb91ea4bff | eff09e2a-c54b-4081-bde5-68de5d32dd73 | owner
 46f9f2e3-edd1-40df-aa52-4bdc354abd38 | 59df2db8-5067-4bc2-b268-3fb1308d9d41 | owner
 9089038d-4b77-4774-a095-a621fb73059a | 4f26ace1-f072-42d0-bd0d-ffbae9103b3f | owner
 5911e84b-ab6f-4a51-942e-dab979882725 | 59df2db8-5067-4bc2-b268-3fb1308d9d41 | rw
```

I have a trigger on update:

```sql
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- trigger that consumes the queue once the user responds
\set obj_name 'sharing_queue_on_update_trigger'

create or replace function :obj_name()
returns trigger as $$
    begin
        if new.status = 'accepted' then
            -- add to the user_permissions table
           insert into core.user_permissions (project_id, user_id, permission)
           values (new.project, new.grantee, new.permission);
        end if;

         -- remove from the queue
        delete from core.sharing_queue
        where core.sharing_queue.grantee = new.grantee
        and core.sharing_queue.project = new.project;

        return null;

    end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger "Create a user_permission entry when user accepts invitation"
    after update on core.sharing_queue
    for each row
    when (new.status != 'awaiting')
    execute procedure :obj_name();
```

When I run the following update:

```sql
update sharing_queue set status='accepted' where project = 'eff09e2a-c54b-4081-bde5-68de5d32dd73';
```

The record in the following queue is supposed to fodder a new record in the first table presented.

```sql
               grantor                | maybe_grantee_email |               project                | permission | creation_date |               grantee                |  status
--------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+----------
 7e3581a4-f542-4abc-bbda-36fb91ea4bff | edmund@gmail.com    | eff09e2a-c54b-4081-bde5-68de5d32dd73 | rw         |               | 46f9f2e3-edd1-40df-aa52-4bdc354abd38 | awaiting
(1 row)
```

Specifically, the grantee with id ending in 38, with the project_id ending in 73 is supposed feed a new record in the first table.

However, I get the following duplicate index error:

```sql
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_project_permissions_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, project_id)=(46f9f2e3-edd1-40df-aa52-4bdc354abd38, eff09e2a-c54b-4081-bde5-68de5d32dd73) already exists.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into core.user_permissions (project_id, user_id, permission)
           values (new.project, new.grantee, new.permission)
           returning new"
```

I don't see how I'm violating the index.  There is no record with the user and project combination in the first table presented.  Right?

I'm new to using triggers this much.  I'm wondering if somehow I might be triggering a "double" entry that cancels the transaction.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

### Requested Addendum

Here is the schema for `user_permissions`

```sql
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  user_permissions
drop table if exists user_permissions;
create table user_permissions (
    user_id    uuid not null,
    project_id uuid not null,
    permission project_permission not null,
    constraint pk_project_permissions_id primary key (user_id, project_id)
);

comment on column user_permissions.permission is 'Enum owner | rw | read';
comment on table user_permissions is 'Cannot add users directly; use sharing_queue';

-- ⚠️  deleted when the user is deleted
alter table user_permissions
add constraint fk_permissions_users
foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
on delete cascade;

-- ⚠️  deleted when the project is deleted
alter table user_permissions
add constraint fk_permissions_projects
foreign key (project_id) references projects(id)
on delete cascade;
```

Comment: Are there more than one row in the queue with project ending in 73?

Comment: what is the schema of `user_permissions`?  Where is `pk_project_permissions_id` defined? Its name suggests it's the PK of `project_permissions`, which is isn't mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  @BjarniRagnarsson There is only one row.  @Bohemian Great point.  I posted the schema for `user_permissions` and the `FK` constraints.  Do  you see anything?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the contents of the `queue`, the issue may be that you're not specifying that the record needs to be changed in your trigger:

```sql
create trigger "Create a user_permission entry when user accepts invitation"
    after update on core.sharing_queue
    for each row
    when ((new.status != 'awaiting') 
      and (old.status IS DISTINCT FROM new.status))
    execute procedure :obj_name();
```

Without the `distinct` check, the trigger would run once for each row where project = 'eff09e2a-c54b-4081-bde5-68de5d32dd73'.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions were helpful as they inspired the direction of the subsequent implementation.  The initial fix using @TonyArra's additional `when` clause seemed to do the trick. The clause was no longer required once I created a series of `on conflict` UPSERT contingencies.